# How can I render a partial view from within a layout file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, render, partials

To add some context, I learned that within a view folder you can just create a file and add a partial with "_partialname", such as "_login".
on my index.html.erb file or any other file I would usually place a:

```
<%= render "login" %>
```

Which is what I did for the layouts folder, but it is not working.

Below is a snippet of my file `/views/layouts/application.html.erb`. Within the same layouts folder, I created a `_footer.html.erb`, which I want all my views to have, but when I try the following, it gives me an error:

```
</head>

<body>
<%= yield %>

<%= render "footer" %>
 </body>
</html>
```

Adding error message:

```
Missing partial static/_footer, application/_footer with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. 
Searched in:
 * "/Users/rogerperez/DevProjects/Property-Pal/app/views"
```

Update: added context on for the reason on my question

Comment: What's the error? (Please add to your question.)

Comment: besides it should be `render partial: 'footer'`...

Comment: both answers below worked.
<%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
<%= render :partial => "layouts/footer" %>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your path is wrong in this case. Change the code to

```
<%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
```

Answer (score 1):

That code will pull in the partial from app/views/layouts/_footer.html.erb.

```
<%= render :partial => "layouts/footer" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

if **_footer.hml.erb** is in layouts folder, then you can render it in : **../views/layouts/application.html.erb** by:

```
<%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
```